# Video edition program that can make several hours long clips from a picture and mp3 files on resolution 480p with only 1 fps

Tags: video, photo-editing

I need a video edition program for Ubuntu 13.04 that can make  several hours long clips from a picture and mp3 files on resolution 480p with only 1 fps. I tried some programs but they cant bet set on 1 fps :*(

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/21768/software-to-create-a-video-slideshow the keyword you are missing is "slideshow"

Comment: No program from that discussion have the required options of 480p 1fps video-file

Comment: Why are you specifically wanting it to be set to "1 FPS"?  Do you mean 1 photo per second?  Are you simply trying to reduce the file size, instead?  If file size is a concern, change encoding methods for all but the audio.  Please specify your needs a bit more clearly and we can probably point you in the right direction.  ;)

Comment: I need to make 5-6 hours long video-clip for Youtube with one picture and 5-6 hours music. I need it to be 480p. Video file with more then one frame per second will be too big - probably hundredths GBs

Comment: Maybe you duplicated your question in this other question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/308205/i-need-to-make-5-6-hours-long-video-clips-for-youtube-with-one-picture-and-5-6-h I suggest you to delete one of your questions that refers to the same topic in order to receive the proper support. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The program `imagination` from the 13.04 repository combined with `avconv` also from the main Raring repository allowed me to make a **1 FPS** video (with music!) just for you.

The destination video file is 693180 octets long for an average of 69KB/second which isn't bad since some of the source images were larger than 100KB and I didn't even bother trying to optimize anything.

The time consuming part of the exercise was signing up to a video hosting service so you could see my 10 second [*magnum opus*](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/7779/r7ajydrtzfivanruiidosb.mp4).

**EDIT** Seeing slides at 1 FPS is pretty fatiguing even for 10 seconds; I can't imagine what 6 hours of that would do. In service to my fans, I made the same video but at 0.2FPS. Of course this bumped the video size up, but one does have to suffer for one's art, I hear. Enjoy the "[director's cut](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2232/te1vigcprzyuyoxoqfhvhz.mp4)"

I don't think you understand how video compression works; parts of an image that stay the same don't require (barely any) extra video data. The increase in file size has a lot to do with there being 5 times as much audio data.